# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [] in DispatcherServlet error

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I am trying an example on spring MVC. I am extending the controller class to Abstract controller and trying to run a small web app, but I am getting the error "WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCExtendingAbstractController/SpringMVCExtendingAbstractController/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'"

Below is the code:

dispatcher-servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean name="/hello" class="com.manjosh.controller.HelloworldController">
        <property name="supportedMethods" value="POST"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>

        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
<display-name>Hello Spring MVC WebApp</display-name>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

controller class:

```
package com.manjosh.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;


public class HelloworldController extends AbstractController{

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {


        return new ModelAndView("welcomePage", "welcomeMessage", "Hello," +req.getParameter("username"));
    }



}
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="SpringMVCExtendingAbstractController/hello" method ="post">
        UserName:<input type="text" name="username"><br> <input
            type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

welcomePage.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>welcomePage</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>${welcomeMessage}</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

error:

```
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 3890 ms
Aug 28, 2017 12:52:56 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCExtendingAbstractController/SpringMVCExtendingAbstractController/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
Aug 28, 2017 12:53:15 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCExtendingAbstractController/SpringMVCExtendingAbstractController/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Comment: You should use spring annotations to configure you spring-mvc application

Comment: It works with annotations. I was just trying using AbstractController class and getting this error. Is there something I am doing wrong in this method?